# Como saber cuantos datos tiene guardado mi vector en C#

Tags: c#

```
int[] VectorImpar = new int[20];
```

El usuario escribe por teclado x numero de datos, ahora bien, lo que el mismo usuario desea es saber fue cuantos datos escribió, lo intente con:

`VectorImpar.legth()` --> y este me da es el valor de la dimensión inicial

`VectorImpar.Count()`  --> también me da el valor inicial del vector

Ninguno de los dos me dice cuántos datos tiene guardados el vector

Comment: Ambas funciones sirven para saber el tamaño del arreglo, por lo tanto, siempre te van a regresar 20.

Answer (score 4):

Hay un problema importante con el planteamiento de tu pregunta. Al inicializar una array de enteros, todos los elementos del array se inicializan a 0 que es el valor por defecto para un `int`. Por lo tanto, si `0` es un posible valor que puede ser introducido, la solución propuesta por @Einer no sería valida, ya que excluiría los ceros que el usuario haya introducido.

Yo veo básicamente dos opciones para solucionar tu problema:

1.- *Inicializar el array con valores que no estén permitidos en la entrada del usuario*. Por ejemplo, si sabemos que los valores negativos no serán nunca introducidos por el usuario, podriamos inicializar el array a `-1` o,por ejemplo al valor minímo que puede introducirse en un `int`(`int.MinValue`), y luego contar los valores que no coincidan:

```
int[] VectorImpar = new int[20];
//Inicializamos el vector
for (int k=0;k<VectorImpar.Length;k++)
{
     VectorImpar[k] = int.MinValue;
}
...
//Para contar los elementos introducidos
int cuenta=VectorImpar.Count(x=>x!=int.MinValue);
```

2.- *Usar una variable para contar los elementos introducidos por el usuario.* Simplemente crea una variable a nivel de clase y ve incrementándola cada vez que se añada un elemento en el array

Answer (score 1):

Dado que es un array simple en el que ya has reservado la memoria, ambas funciones te darán el tamaño inicial del array. Te recomiendo usar alguna clase auxiliar como:

```
List<int> integers = new List<int>();
integers.Add(1);
integers.Add(4);
integers.Add(7);

int someElement = integers[1];
```

Estas clases te permiten conocer el tamaño del array con esas funciones. También te permiten no tener que reservar un tamaño de memoria X, sino que se va reservando de forma dinámica.

### Editado:

En caso de que el tamaño deba estar dado y sabiendo que un trabajo de clase, te recomiendo que te crees tu propia clase "MiVector" la cuál tiene como atributos un `int[] vector` y un `int contador`.

#### Ejemplo con pseudocódigo:

```
 public class MiVector
   {
      // Class MiVector.
      private int[] vector;
      private int contador;
      public int MiVector(int size)
      {
          vector = new int[size];
          contador = 0;
      }
      //comportamiento de una cola (FIFO)
      public void set(int value)
      {
          vector[contador]=value;
          contador++;
      }

      public int  get(int indice)
      {
          return vector[indice];
      }
   }
```

También podrías darle un uso como `MiVector[5]`, para eso tendrías que [sobrecargar el operador](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms228498(v=vs.90).aspx).

### Otra opción (Complementando la que te han dicho los compañeros):

Trabajar de esta forma:

```
int[] VectorImpar = new int[20];
int totalElementos = 0;
VertorImpar[0] = 22;
totalElementos++;
VertorImpar[1]++;
```

Espero que esto responda a tu pregunta.

Comment: El programa debe tener ya, reservado el tamaño x de la memoria y no puede ser de forma dinamica por restricciones del docente, no tienes otro ejemplo que me puedas facilitar?

Comment: Echa un ojo a la respuesta editada @deibystevenperalta

Comment: Daniel: creo que te has colado y has intentado editar otra respuesta en lugar de editar la tuya. La sugerencia de edición está en https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/61488, por si quieres recuperar el contenido de allí.

Comment: Ya he editado mi respuesta. Perdón por si edité la de otra persona.

Comment: @DanielGS ya solucione el problema, le agrege un par de contadores y asi soluciono el problema, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Puedes lograrlo utilizando el metodo `Where`, buscando todos los indices con el valor igual a 0:

```
int[] VectorImpar = new int[20];
VertorImpar[0] = 22;
VertorImpar[1] = -55;
int totalElementos = VertorImpar.Where(x=> x == 0).Count(); 
Console.WriteLine(totalElementos.ToString()); // 18
```

El metodo `Where()` filtra la coleccion por los elementos que complan la condicion en el metodo que se le envio por parametros y luego el metodo Count() cuenta el resultado del filtro.

Aunque no es asi como se se traduce el uso del metodo Where con el metodo Count, aqui una idea de como seria en escencia y como utilizando sin el metodo:

```
 int totalVacios = 0;
    foreach(int i in VertorImpar)
    {
       if(i==0)
       {
          totalVacios++;
       }
    }

Console.WriteLine(totalVacios.ToString());
```

Comment: Me puedes ilustrar un poco mejor en la forma de usar este metodo, y al momento de usarlo en pseudocodigo como seria para hacer lo mismo sin el metodo?

Comment: Actualize mi pregunta. Dale una mirada.

Comment: @deibystevenperalta siempre y cuando el usuario no escriba `0` como valor o no, ¿debería poder ingresar cero?.

Comment: @Einer ya solucione el problema, le agrege un par de contadores y asi soluciono el problema

Comment: Excelente, me alegra saberlo.